# regex to do a non-contiguous find and replace

Tags: regex

Often, I run into situations where I'd like to find and replace two sides of a string, and leave the middle intact.  Usually, the first part is easy enough to identify, but the second part is too common.  Here is an example:

To change the code string `ActiveDocument.Sections["SectionName"]` to `SectionName`, it's easy to find the first part, but the latter `"]` is way too common without its relationship to `ActiveDocument.Sections["`.  Obviously, if `SectionName` was a static string, this wouldn't matter, I can just find the whole code string, inclusive, to replace.

Is there a way to match both sides, skipping the middle, or can regex only find contiguous parts?  Or maybe there's a way of doing what I want by temporarily storing what's found by `.*?` in an expression?

I'm using UltraEdit for my find/replace operation.  I can also use Javascript to execute on the code as a string ie: `codestring.replace()`

Comment: fwiw, in UltraEdit, I had to change the regex type to Perl to use Jay's answer.

Comment: I've been going through my reputation stuff, not only taking a nostalgic trip, but also seeing if I could add details to repair my rep.  I re-found this gem.  I have to say, this question and the answer @Jay gave quite literally changed my life.  My use of regex jumped exponentially once I was able to retain interstitial information.  Not only that, but I was able to convert others who were still finding creative ways to use Windows  find/replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to depend on the tool you use, but in Javascript you can use `$1` to return the first capture group.

So you can use the pattern `ActiveDocument.Sections\["(.*?)"\]` for "find" and `$1` for "replace".

I tested this with the javascript regex tool at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Comment: `.*` is creedy and will match until the last `"]` in the entire document. use the lazy `.*?`.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to test this and mark yours as the answer. Thank you so much for your response; it's gonna make my life easier here on out. My pattern was `ActiveDocument\.Sections\[\"Dashboard\"\]\.Shapes\[\"(.*?)\"\]` Not sure why yours works ... since you didn't escape the first dot, shouldn't that change $1 to "." and make what I'm looking for $2 in your example?

Comment: I think I figured it out ... the paretheses around `.*?` seems to make the difference.

Comment: @EdwardD Paretheses by default indicate a "capture group," so that corresponds to $1. If you have more than one set of parentheses, they would populate $2, $3 *etc.*

Answer (score 0):

`.*\["(.*?)"\]`worked for me in Python

```
import re
re.match(r'.*\["(.*?)"\]', 'ActiveDocument.Sections["SectionName"]').group(1)
'SectionName'
```

Based on an [online test](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), it appears to work with Javascript as well.